# Check if Browser Exists in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest, user-agent

I'm trying to write an web application that, if the request comes from a browser, produces a file, but if it comes from another source (say, for example, a Windows service hitting the site to retrieve a response) it would simply return the response generated.

Would this work?

```
if (Request.Browser == null)
{
    Response.Write(response);
}
else
{
    Response.Write("You're in a browser. Go Away.");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it to see if it works?

Comment: Not sure how I can hit a website without a browser to make that test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how secure/reliable you want it to be. Assuming that you have control over the Windows Service, a simple way would be to have it specify a specific user-agent string. Then a simple check like this would suffice:

```
if (Request.UserAgent == "MyWindowsService")
{
    Response.Write(response);
}
else
{
    Response.Write("You're in a browser. Go Away.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob! I don't have control of the service, but i was able to resolve the problem in a different way (by removing this requirement all together :P).